# Getting started with the new Visual Studio Visualization and Modeling SDK (was DSL SDK)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dsl-tools

Is there  a good guide on how to setup and use the new Visual Studio Visualization and Modeling SDK with vs 2010 and vs 2008 ?
reference:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you have a look to the [DSL Tools Lab](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DslToolsLab).